# R assigning probability of an answer

Tags: r, probability

I have 100 tasks and 20 people to do those tasks. I assign 7 tasks at random to each person (so as to calculate inter-rater agreement later). So I have a dataSet which has personID, taskID. There are 5 possible answers for each task. I simulate the "truth" answer (from the 5 possible answers) by

`truth <- sample(answers, no.tasks, replace = FALSE, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))`

and add this to my dataSet which has now three columns: personID, taskID, truth;

I also say that 50% of the people perform poorly (poorperson) and 10% of tasks are hard tasks (hardtasks).  I assume the probabilities for each: poor performance, good performance, hard task, easy task

```
ppoor <- 0.7
pgood <- 0.99
phard <- 0.2
peasy <- 0.8
```

Now, I need to simulate the person's answer based on whether she is a good or poor at the task and also whether the task is easy or hard. For one such combination I am doing:

`for(i in 1:length(dataSet$taskID)) { ifelse(dataSet$personID[i] %in% poorperson && dataSet[dataSet$personID == i,]$taskID %in% hardtasks, probs[i] <- ppoor * phard, NA)}`

But, I don't get what I expect i.e. I want to get the 'probs' for each task and worker combination. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Would be really helpful if we could run your code to help you. Can you make a reproducible example? see dput()

Comment: @EvanFriedland, Thank you. I couldn't really figure out dput() but here is the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ePfpQUkw9xd1I0YkFfRWtIQ1k. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble understanding your code but I rewrote it in a way that I hope opens discussion on what you need moving forward. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
# Initialize 
no.tasks <- 100
no.workers <- 20 
tasksperworker <- no.tasks/no.workers # 5 each ( why did you have 7?)

# ANSWERS for Tasks
answers <- c("liver", "blood", "lung", "brain", "heart")
(truth <- sample(answers, no.tasks, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))

# TASKS
prop_hardtasks <- .10
hardtasks <- sample(1:no.tasks, prop_hardtasks * no.tasks)
easytasks <- setdiff(1:no.tasks, hardtasks)
phard <- 0.2
peasy <- 0.8
(task_Difficulty <- ifelse(1:no.tasks %in% easytasks, peasy, phard))

# WORKERS
prop_poorworkers <- .50 
poorworkers <- sample(1:no.workers, prop_poorworkers * no.workers)
goodworkers <- setdiff(1:no.workers, poorworkers)
ppoor <- 0.7
pgood <- 0.99
(worker_Ability <- ifelse(1:no.workers %in% goodworkers, pgood, ppoor))

# The dataset
# One step data creation
dataSet <- data.frame("workerID" = rep(1:no.workers, each = tasksperworker), 
                  "taskID" = 1:no.tasks, 
                  "truth" = truth, 
                  "taskDifficulty" = factor(task_Difficulty, labels = c("hard","easy")), 
                  "workerAbility" = factor(rep(worker_Ability, each = tasksperworker), labels = c("poor","good")), 
                  "probCorrect" = task_Difficulty * worker_Ability)

# I am coding out the old method as I believe it samples twice which is not necessary
# (assignmentMatrix <- replicate(no.workers, sample(1:no.tasks, tasksperworker, replace=FALSE))) 
#(assignEach <- reshape::melt.matrix(assignmentMatrix))
#(dataSet <- cbind.data.frame("workerID" = assignEach[,2], 
#                             "taskID" = assignEach[,3], 
#                             "truth" = truth[assignEach[,2]], 
#                             "taskDifficulty" = factor(task_Difficulty, labels = c("hard",'easy')), 
#                             "workerAbility" = factor(rep(worker_Ability,each = tasksperworker), labels = c("poor","good")), 
#                             "probCorrect" = task_Difficulty * worker_Ability))
```

**EDIT** as requested:

Given there are 5 possibilities and there is one truth for each task (which we randomly generate), we want to save the probability that the worker gets the answer right, while assigning the other possible answers the remaining probability. This vector is likely changing for each task/worker. The `sample(..., prob)` argument must always equal 1. Thus I went ahead and did the following:

```
# Initialize a matrix where each row contains the probability vector we will use to sample. 
truthProb <- matrix(NA, nrow = no.tasks, ncol = length(answers), dimnames = list(1:no.tasks, answers)) 

# run a for loop to populate it
for(i in 1:no.tasks){
  # Because Answer always changes, 
  # Find location of truth amongst answer vector using which
  # And place the probCorrect value into that spot
  truthProb[i, which(answers %in% dataSet$truth[i])] <- dataSet$probCorrect[i]
  # I would assign equal remaining probabilities to other incorrect answers.
  truthProb[i, -which(answers %in% dataSet$truth[i])] <- (1 - dataSet$probCorrect[i]) / (length(answers) - 1) 
}
rowSums(truthProb) # Should sum to 1

# Add their answers here by using apply to say, given a probability from each row (task), draw the single answer
dataSet$results <- apply(truthProb, 1, function(x) sample(answers, 1, replace = F, prob = x)) 

tail(truthProb) # see the probabilities for each task
tail(dataSet) # can compare the last bit

# how did we do? table showing results at each probCorrect (combination of difficulty and ability)
table(dataSet$truth, dataSet$results, dataSet$probCorrect) 

# double check again that this idea works as intended...
dataSet$truth[1]
truthProb[1,]
sum(1 * (dataSet$truth[1] == replicate(100, sample(answers, 1, replace = F, prob = truthProb[1,])))) /100
```

**EDIT a function version of it all:**

```
# Simulate a Function!!
sim <- function(answers, no.tasks, no.workers, prop_hardtasks, prop_poorworkers, prob_hardeasy, prob_poorgood){
  # Initialize 
  tasksperworker <- no.tasks/no.workers
  # ANSWERS for Tasks
  truth <- sample(answers, no.tasks, replace = TRUE) # assumes equal probability of each answer
  # TASKS
  hardtasks <- sample(1:no.tasks, prop_hardtasks * no.tasks)
  easytasks <- setdiff(1:no.tasks, hardtasks)
  phard <- prob_hardeasy[1]
  peasy <- prob_hardeasy[2]
  (task_Difficulty <- ifelse(1:no.tasks %in% easytasks, peasy, phard))
  # WORKERS
  poorworkers <- sample(1:no.workers, prop_poorworkers * no.workers)
  goodworkers <- setdiff(1:no.workers, poorworkers)
  ppoor <- prob_poorgood[1]
  pgood <- prob_poorgood[2]
  (worker_Ability <- ifelse(1:no.workers %in% goodworkers, pgood, ppoor))
  # One step data creation
  dataSet <- data.frame("workerID" = rep(1:no.workers, each = tasksperworker), 
                        "taskID" = 1:no.tasks, "truth" = truth, "taskDifficulty" = factor(task_Difficulty, labels = c("hard","easy")), 
                        "workerAbility" = factor(rep(worker_Ability, each = tasksperworker), labels = c("poor","good")), 
                        "probCorrect" = task_Difficulty * rep(worker_Ability, each = tasksperworker))
  # SIMULATE ANSWER
  truthProb <- matrix(NA, nrow = no.tasks, ncol = length(answers), dimnames = list(1:no.tasks, answers)) 
  for(i in 1:no.tasks){
    truthProb[i, which(answers %in% dataSet$truth[i])] <- dataSet$probCorrect[i]
    truthProb[i, -which(answers %in% dataSet$truth[i])] <- (1 - dataSet$probCorrect[i]) / (length(answers) - 1) 
  }
  dataSet$results <- apply(truthProb, 1, function(x) sample(answers, 1, replace = F, prob = x)) 
  # Return
  return(dataSet)
}

dat <- sim(answers = LETTERS[1:5],  #  c("liver", "blood", "lung", "brain", "heart")
           no.tasks = 100, 
           prop_hardtasks = 10/100, 
           prob_hardeasy = c(.2, .8),
           no.workers = 20, 
           prop_poorworkers = 10/20, 
           prob_poorgood = c(.77, .99))
head(dat)
table(dat$truth, dat$results, dat$probCorrect)
```

Comment: thank you! I had 7 workers because I want the no. of workers per task to be always an odd number more than the possible no. of answers (in this case 5). Replace was TRUE because I want multiple workers to do one task. I see what you did which is so much easier & straightforward than what I was trying to do.

Comment: @amrapaliz happy to help! If you have further trouble making this work the way you need to, just comment again~

Comment: Also, I had the factor(, labels) incorrect in the first part. Had to switch c("easy","hard") and c("good","poor") to c("hard", "easy") and c("poor","good")

Comment: Actually, when I look at the results I notice workerAbility changes even though the workerID does not... will update

Comment: Please see all edits above. The dataset creation step no longer need reshape as it works in base R. I figured since we sample the task difficulties to start, there is no need to resample as was done with assigneach.

Comment: Ok I was actually trying "for(i in 1:length(dataSet$taskID)){
  workerAnswer[i] <- sample(answers, 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(dataSet$probCorrect[i], (1 - dataSet$probCorrect[i])/4, (1 - dataSet$probCorrect[i])/4, (1 - dataSet$probCorrect[i])/4, (1 - dataSet$probCorrect[i])/4)) }"

Comment: Oh I see I am looking at it now.

Comment: Ok yes now it is working as intended. Thank you! This was indeed a bit more complicated than what I was thinking.

Comment: It did seem a little much didn't it? Perhaps it could have been made simpler. But this way it is very easy to create a function. Check the update

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a lot ! That is indeed extremely helpful.

Comment: Hi @Evan Friedland, would you be able to help me further with this program? Can I get your email?

Comment: Actually just found an error looking back at this code... when making the dataframe dataset, "probCorrect" should be = task_Difficulty * rep****(worker_Ability, each = tasksperworker)***....